# how to flattern the array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying flattern the array of object . I am able to do that . I just want to know is it correct way to do that or is there any better library available ?

**Data**

```
const data = {
      details: [
        {
          item_details: {
            number: "sdas",
            date: "28/07/2022"
          }
        },
        {
          item_details: {
            number: "hello",
            date: "28/07/2022"
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

**Code**

```
function convetObj(data) {
  let res = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < data.details.length; i++) {
    res[`details[${i}].item_details.number`] =
      data.details[i].item_details.number;
    res[`details[${i}].item_details.date`] = data.details[i].item_details.date;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(convetObj(data));
```

Here is my code at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sky-576rwn?file=/src/App.js:24-774)

I am getting same as expected output, but wanted to know is it better way ? any better library available

**expected output**

```
{
  details[0].item_details.number:"sdas",
  details[0].item_details.date:"28/07/2022"
  details[1].item_details.number:"hello",
  details[1].item_details.date:"28/07/2022"
}
```

**actual output**

```
{
 "details[0].item_details.number": "sdas",
 "details[0].item_details.date": "28/07/2022",
 "details[1].item_details.number": "hello",
 "details[1].item_details.date": "28/07/2022"
}
```

Comment: why not just `const mapped = data.details.map(item => item.item_details)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With recursion you can flatten an object of any structure, so it's generic, can be reused on any object, seems better than flatten object every time manually:

```js
const flatten = (obj, target = {}, path = '') => {
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    for(let i = 0; i< obj.length; i++){
      flatten(obj[i], target, `${path}[${i}]`);
    }
  }else if(obj.__proto__ === Object.prototype){
    for(const key in obj){
      flatten(obj[key], target, `${path}${path ? '.' : ''}${key}`);
    }
  }else{
     target[path] = obj;
  }
  
  return target;
};

console.log(flatten(data));
```

```html
<script>
const data = {
      details: [
        {
          item_details: {
            number: "sdas",
            date: "28/07/2022"
          }
        },
        {
          item_details: {
            number: "hello",
            date: "28/07/2022"
          }
        }
      ]
    };

</script>
```

Comment: the question the OP asked is for a "better" way. Your answer doesn't address the question. In what ways (that aren't opinionated or subjective) is this "better"?

Comment: @devlincarnate why it's not better, at least it's generic, can be reused, doesn't depend on an object structure

Comment: thanks @AlexanderNenashev it look good to me